# Can you do an INSERT with a subuery *AND* add additional information?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables almost identical:

- `employee`
- `employee_history`

The second table has two additional fields.

I would like to copy a record from `employee` into `employee_history` using an INSERT with a subquery.  Sort of like this:

```
INSERT INTO employee_history SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = idQ
```

My problem is that I need to add information into the 2 fields `employee_history` has that `employee` does not have:

- `update_code`
- `date_of_change`.

Is there a way I can copy a record from `employee` into `employee_history` keeping it simple like with the above insert statement while adding the 2 new pieces of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the `employee` table and select all the columns then add the two new columns wherever they fit (at the beginning or end of the list):

```
INSERT INTO employee_history SELECT e.*, 'x', 'y' FROM employee e WHERE id = idQ;
```

You need to alias the table because you would get an error (`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`) if you ran it as such:

```
INSERT INTO employee_history SELECT *, 'x', 'y' FROM employee WHERE id = idQ;
```

The problem would be if your two additional columns in the `employee_history` table were in the middle of the list of columns in the `employee` table. In that case you'd have to individually select each column.

Comment: Cool!  This is a super convenient way of doing it!  Thanks John!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO employee_history 
SELECT emp.field1, emp.field2, emp.field3, 'new value A', 'new value b'
FROM employee emp
WHERE emp.id = idQ
```

Comment: This is very useful for situations where the "new" fields don't come in order at the end.  Thanks a ton Alex!